# Every expression with "array of type" will always be converted to "pointer to array of type" in C

Tags: c, types, expression, c99

Example code:

```cpp
int a[10]={0};
a = (void *) 0; // error: assignment to expression with array type
```

According to [6.5.1 Primary expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)

```
primary-expression:
 identifier
 constant
 string-literal
 ( expression )
```

and [6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)

> **An lvalue is an expression with an object type or an incomplete type other than void;**
> if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined.
> When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the lvalue used to
> designate the object. **A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type,** does
> not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type, and if it is a structure
> or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of
> all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.

We know both `a` and `(void *) 0` are l-value expression and `a` has a array of type.

If we look following definition:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a
> string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is
> converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of
> the array object and is not an lvalue.** If the array object has register storage class, the
> behavior is undefined.

Looks like type of `a` transfer from `array of int` to `pointer to array of int`, it becomes "modifiable lvalue". But my gcc 9.3.0 said:

```
error: assignment to expression with array type"
```

I am confused.

Comment: "*Looks like type of `a` transfer from `array of int` to `pointer to array of int`*" - no, it **decays** into a `pointer to int`. A `pointer to array of int` is something else completely different. "*it becomes "modifiable lvalue"*" - no, it doesn't, in this context. **Array decay** only happens in certain contexts (like passing an array to a function parameter, or assigning it to a variable), but this is not one of them. So, you can't assign *anything* to an array itself once it has been initialized, only to its elements.

Comment: `(void *) 0` does not look like an l-value to me

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for correction. The description of array decay in function declaration can be found in `6.7.5.3 Function declarators`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you missed is section 6.5.16p2 regarding constraints on Assignment Operators:

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand

An array is not a modifiable lvalue, therefore it's a constraint violation to have it on the left side of an assignment.

Also, `(void *)0` is not an lvalue, as per footnote 104 on 6.5.4p5:

> A cast  does  not  yield  an  lvalue.   Thus, a cast  to  a  qualified  type  has  the  same  effect  as  a  cast  to  the unqualified version of the type.

Comment: Thanks for your and @John Bollinger further explanation. Another question, if I change the above to `(*a) = 5`, it will turn out to `(* (&a[0])) = 5` and `(* (&a[0]))` is a modifiable lvalue?

Comment: @5f3759df0x That's fine, because the unary `*` operator yields an lvalue, which in this case has type `int`.

Comment: I had been obsessed by the question all the day. If I could give you hug I would maybe that would be a better way to show my very immense gratitude.

Comment: @5f3759df0x Around here, we do that by [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like type of a transfer from array of int to pointer to array of int, it becomes "modifiable lvalue".

No, it doesn't.  Per the definition already included in the question, `a` is converted to an expression of type "pointer to `int`" *that is **not** an lvalue*.  Among the consequences of the result not being an lvalue is that you cannot assign to (whole) arrays.

> But my gcc 9.3.0 said:
>
> ```
> error: assignment to expression with array type"
> ```

... which is easier to understand than "assignment to an expression that is not an lvalue".